# Representation of states in $C^*$-algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a $C^* $-algebra, let $\pi : \mathfrak{A} \to \mathcal{B}(H)$ be a representation of $\mathfrak{A}$ on the space of bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space $H$ and let $\omega: \mathfrak{A} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a state on $\mathfrak{A} $. Now consider the map $\tau $ defined by the functional relation

$$\tau \big( \pi (A ) \big) = \omega(A) \, , \quad \forall A \in \mathfrak{A} \, .$$

In order for this to be well-defined, $\pi$ needs to be injective. But then $\pi$ is automatically an isomorphism, and thus $\pi(\mathfrak{A})$ is itself a $C^*$-algebra and the above defines a state $\tau : \pi (\mathfrak{A}) \to \mathbb{C}$. Furthermore, one can invoke the Hahn-Banach theorem to extend $\tau$ to a state on the whole $\mathcal{B}(H)$.

**Question 1:** is the above construction of the state $\tau :  \mathcal{B}(H) \to \mathbb{C}$ for any $\pi$ (injective) and $\omega$ correct?

**Question 2:** what are the properties of $\tau$ given $\pi$ and $\omega$? For instance, when is $\tau$ normal?

Comment: Did you try asking this on math.stackexchange first? It isn't really research level.

Comment: @NikWeaver I did, but I didn't get any answer.

Comment: I see. You are right that any state on $A$ can be transferred to a state on $\pi(A)$ if $A \cong \pi(A)$. The sentence "in order for this to be well-defined" isn't strictly accurate, unless you mean "well-defined for any choice of $\omega$". To your second question, since there are no restrictions on $\omega$ I don't think there's a lot you can say about $\tau$ other than "it extends $\omega$ to $B(H)$".

Comment: @NikWeaver yes you are right, for a fixed $\omega$ you don’t need $\pi$ to be injective, it just needs to satisfy a weaker property that depends on $\omega$.